# Implement message sender for Artemis 2.17.0 in Java 6 and GlassFish server

Tags: java, jms, activemq-artemis

I'm working in an rather old system that uses Java 6 and is deployed in GlassFish 2.1 server.

In that system I need to develop a message sender to ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0. Is there a way to achieve this?

I have been searching for solutions but the compatibility issues are a constant problem.

Comment: In my opinion you're probably better off upgrading the system to a supported Java and Glassfish version than trying to circumvent the compatibility issues.

Comment: Hey Jeroen, thanks for taking a moment to answer. I wish I could do that but is not an option

Answer (score 1):

It is *possible*, but it's not going to be convenient. You can use any of the following that still support Java 6:

- An older ActiveMQ Artemis client. I think the latest ActiveMQ Artemis client that *could* be built with Java 6 was 1.1.0, but the release was actually built with Java 7 so you'd have to build the client yourself.
- An older HornetQ client. I'd recommend something in 2.3.x or 2.4.x. You might have to build one of those yourself as well.
- An older OpenWire JMS client.
- An older STOMP client.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Which version of ActiveMQ Artemis client do you think it could work?

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment. I hope that helps!